# UIImage disappears when trying to set text of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using this code to initialize text labels in a UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setText: [menuTitlesEN objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

My table consists of four static cells, each containing a UIImageView and a UILabel.

When `setText` is not called, my table looks as it should:

[image: Screenshot 1]

But calling `setText` leads to `UIImage`s somehow disappearing:

[image]

I'm *very* new to iOS development. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: How do the cells end up looking the way they do in the first image?

Comment: I have a feeling since in your source code the name of the NSString you define `CellIdentifier` is highlighted blue, I can only assume that it happens to also be the same name you are using in your .h file for your image icon.

Comment: @SantaClaus when I remark the call to `setText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to you'r overriding the `UILabel` of default cell's(`cell.textLabel`). So you better give the tag property to your custom `UILabel` in the `UITableViewCell` and then assign text to it .

Try Similar :

```
UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:identityOfUILabel];
[lbl setText: [menuTitlesEN objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: This works, but would you please describe what's the different? Does accessing `cell.textLabel` dispose of any views embedded inside the cell, and instead create a simple `UILabel`?

Comment: **By default the Cell has set of styles,** you can look at those . By default the `UITableViewCell` has a title(`UILabel`) and `UIImageView` within the cell. If your tried to use these then the embedded views will overlap with these. *You need to make custom Cell by your own, OR else simply use the default UITabelViewCell views*

Answer (score 1):

Try like this may be helpfull

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image name that you have"];
    [cell.textLabel setText: [menuTitlesEN objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks